# virtual host not working when cloudflare is enabled

Tags: apache, .htaccess, virtualhost, cloudflare

Before cloudflare, I was able to access the phpMyAdmin link such as

`example.com/ctrl/pmasetup`

After CloudFlare, I get a 403 (coming from my own apache server, not CloudFlare's error page)

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /ctrl/pmasetup on this server.
```

I feel like I need to add the CloudFlare's reverse proxy somewhere on the server, which I did in `/etc/hosts` which now looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain
104.25.68.32 example.com <- This is the ip of my site when CloudFlare is enabled on it
```

I also added it in `httpd.conf` in the virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin support@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ErrorLog logs/example.com-error_log
        CustomLog logs/example.com-access_log combinedio
        Alias /ctrl /var/www/ctrl
        <Location /ctrl>
                <RequireAny>
                        Require all denied
                        Require ip {my ip}
                        Require ip 104.25.68.32 <- CloudFlare IP, again
                </RequireAny>
        </Location>
        #Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://example.com"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS"
        Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit: Even when commenting the entire `RequireAny` block, I still get a 403 when CloudFlare is enabled.

Edit 2: if inside the `location` tag I ONLY have `Require all granted`, then it works. So, how can I disallow everybody BUT the few IP's I put initially?

Edit 3: It most likely is because CloudFlare changes your IP as a visitor, then my apache config doesn't recognize it. Any idea?

Comment: Install [mod_cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/technical-resources/#mod_cloudflare), keep your old working rules. Be sure to update your config if they add ranges to theis [ips](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/)

Comment: ... and if you're not able to install mod_cloudflare, inspect the `CF-Connecting-IP` header instead, but _only_ for if  `REMOTE_ADDR` is in the ranges as per the ip page, so be prepared to create a lot of rules (you can set up a huge list of `RewriteCond`'s for a Forbidden `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED** -- See below;

I believe you should allow cloudflare's ip ranges to access the site. After all, the request comes from cloudflare not the client.

CloudFlare's ip ranges can be found on their website at:
https://www.cloudflare.com/ips/

They also provide an easy "text/plain" format following both theses urls:

[CloudFlare IPv4 Ranges](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v4) & [CloudFlare IPv6 Ranges](https://www.cloudflare.com/ips-v6)

There's also a little tool i know of, for nginx tho, available at:

https://www.8ball.me/nginx/ngx-cfips.zip

**EDIT** -- I've created a new version since this post. Today actually (2017.05.31). The url is still valid. It's got a --help function detailing how to setup as a cronjob and include into nginx. Same CloudFlare urls are used.

Answer (score 0):

When there is an option denying I believe you need to use RequireAll instead of RequireAny (since RequireAny is the default behaviour in 2.4 so there is no need to specify it like you do). Try it.

Comment: I changed `RequireAny` for `RequiredAll` -- same problem.